# RESTful route angular route provider

Tags: rest, angularjs, route-provider

I would like to do something like this:

```
$routeProvider 
   .when '/playlists/:playlistId',
      templateUrl: '/partials/playlists/show.html'
   .when '/playlists/new',
      templateUrl: '/partials/playlists/new.html'
```

unfortunately, angular seems to think "new" is a :playlistId

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your route's positions and wrap the templateUrl in the params object:

```
$routeProvider 
  .when '/playlists/new',
     {templateUrl: '/partials/playlists/new.html'}
  .when '/playlists/:playlistId',
     {templateUrl: '/partials/playlists/show.html'}
```

I'm not sure the solution is final but I think it will work since angular parses the routes sequentially
and, by the way, I think it's better to have two separate controllers for those two actions (`new` and `playlistId`).

Comment: i didn't have brackets around templateUrl bc I'm using coffeescript, the order helped.